# Javascript -- missing semicolon (no)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following code:

```js
...

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function refreshField() {
    var c = null;
    while (c == null) {
        c = document.getElementById("textbox");
        await sleep(10);
    }
    var lines = c.value.split("\n");

    cells = new Cartesian();

    for (var i in lines) {
        var line = lines[i];
        var pts = line.trimRight().split(" ").map(Number).filter(function(x) { return !isNaN(x); });
        for (var j = 0; j + 1 < pts.length; j += 2) {
            cells.add([pts[j], -pts[j + 1]]);
        }
    }

    fieldDrawEvent = setTimeout(drawField, 10);
}

...
```

It works properly in chromium and opera, while in firefox 41.0.2 it says that a semicolon is missing right after the "async" word. I can't figure out why. The rest of the code is not so important, I guess, but I can't be sure. Can you help me to locate the error?

Btw, it also works fine in firefox 53.0.3.

Comment: Did you try using `var async function`?

Comment: `async` not supported until Firefox 52.0 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thank you, it's the reason, I guess. I'll try to find another way to sleep for 10 ms.

Comment: @pedro That would be incorrect syntax.

Comment: @Xufox I realised once I had written it and checked developer.mozilla.org.

Comment: @Golovanov399 Just use a transpiler if you need code that works in older browsers as well (even when this particular one is pretty simple to convert manually to `then` syntax)